# Array max consecutive sum of k possible elements

Tags: c++

> Given array of integers, find the maximal possible sum of some of its
> k consecutive elements.
>
> ```
> Example
>
> For inputArray = [2, 3, 5, 1, 6]
> ```
>
> and k = 2, the output should be
> solution(inputArray, k) = 8.

So my program kind of works, at least the test cases that I have seen, except for the fact that it skips the first element.

There are probably multiple ways of solving it. Either by inserting a copy of the first element to the array or make a seperate loop that loops through the first check (2+3 = 5). But none of these solutions really seem to be elegant enough. I want to solve this the best possible way and I cant seem to a good solution. This is my code:

```
vector<int> arr = {1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 19, 1};
    int sum {};
    int max {};
    int k = 3;

for (int i {}; i < arr.size(); ++i)
{
    sum = 0;
    int x = k;

    for (int j = i+1; j < arr.size(); ++j)
    {
        sum += arr.at(j);
        --x;
        
        if (x == 0)
        {
            cout << sum << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (sum > max)
    {
        max = sum;
    }
}

cout << max << endl;
```

As you can see my inner for loop starts with the index `j+1` so it skips the first index in the vector by default. How do I fix this? Is there an if-statement I can do to manipulate the loop to only have `j = i+1 if i != 0?`

Comment: How about `sum = arr[i];` rather than `sum = 0;` before heading into the `j` loop. Or perhaps I missed the forest for the trees. (and `int x = (k-1);`, hopefully obvious).

Comment: Thats smarter. I put sum = arr.at(i) and x = k-1. But the problem occurs when k = 1. For instance for {3, 2, 1, 1} the output will be 7 when its supposed to be 3.

Comment: why not sort the array with `std::sort' then it is just a matter of adding the num of elements you need?

Comment: "the best possible way" is something never defined.

Comment: I'm afraid that I dont quite understand what you mean. If I sort the vector it will not work according to the test cases. I dont think I should edit the vector.

Comment: so make a copy of it :) https://onlinegdb.com/pYtdb5DRl

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an if-statement I can do to manipulate the loop to only have `j = i+1 if i != 0`?

You can use a ternary operator to do it, something like that:

```
int j = i != 0 ? i + 1 : i;
```

Structure of a ternary operator:
[image]

---

But, I got curious: why you don't add the value `i` to the sum (so it's always part of the sum), instead of starting it with zero?

```
sum = array[i];
```

Comment: Thats smarter. I put sum = arr.at(i) and x = k-1. But the problem occurs when k = 1. For instance for {3, 2, 1, 1} the output will be 7 when its supposed to be 3

Answer (score 0):

> There are probably multiple ways of solving it. [...] I want to solve this the best possible way.

Then, consider a O(N) algorithm, instead of a O(N^2) one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

auto max_sum_of_k(std::vector<int> const& v, size_t k)
{
  // Sum the first k elements.
  long long current_sum{};
  size_t i{};
  for ( ; i < k and i < v.size(); ++i )
  {
    current_sum += v[i];
  }
  
  // Update the running sum, without a nested loop. 
  long long sum{ current_sum };
  for ( ; i < v.size(); ++i )
  {
    current_sum -= v[i - k];
    current_sum += v[i];
    if ( sum < current_sum )
      sum = current_sum;
  }
  return sum;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> arr = {1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 19, 1};

  for (size_t k{}; k <= arr.size(); ++k)
  {
      std::cout << "k: " << k << "  max sum: " << max_sum_of_k(arr, k) << '\n';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First note that this task is only possible if `k` does not exceed the array length.

Now an efficient solution is to

- compute the sum of the first k elements, then
- repeatedly remove the first element from the sum and add the next one. This makes a significant saving.

---

```
int j;
int Sum= A[0];
for (j= 1; j < k; j++)
  Sum+= A[j];

// Here we have the first sum

for ( ; j < length; j++)
{
  Sum-= A[j - k];
  Sum+= A[j];

  // Here we have the next sums
}
```

I leave you as an exercise to keep the maximum sum.

Notice that the sum update trick is not recommended for floating-point types, due to the accumulation of numerical errors.

Answer (score 0):

A bit fancy way to do it, using templates:

```cpp
template <typename In>
auto sum_at_most_n(In b, In e, size_t n) {
    typename std::iterator_traits<In>::value_type sum{};
    while (b != e && n--) {
        sum = sum + *b++;
    }
    return std::pair{sum, b};
}

template <typename In>
auto max_sum_of_k(In b, In e, size_t k) {
    auto [sum, head] = sum_at_most_n(b, e, k);
    auto max_sum = sum;
    while (head != e) {
        sum = sum - *b++ + *head++;
        max_sum = std::max(max_sum, sum);
    }
    return max_sum;
}

template <typename Container>
auto max_sum_of_k(Container c, size_t k) ->
    typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::begin(c))>::value_type {
    return max_sum_of_k(std::begin(c), std::end(c), k);
}
```

Just iterating over elements and then subtraction elements which are no longer part of the sum,
but I really recommend to learn how to write tests. See link with demo:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6joa3h4TY)